# CodeIgniter llenar formulario con datos. HTML. PHP

Tags: php, html, codeigniter

Buenas tardes en mi pagina lo que debo hacer es en base a un id consultar en la base de datos traer los datos y llenar un formulario esto usando CodeIgniter, html y php.
en la siguiente linea en base a un id lo envió al controlador:

```
<td scope="row"><a href='<?php echo base_url();?>agenda/agendaC/actualizaAgenda/<?php echo $dato['id'];?>'><img src='<?php echo base_url();?>estilo/images/iconos/editar.png' title='Editar' /></a></td>
```

CONTROLLADOR

```
 public function actualizaAgenda($id = NULL){


    $this->load->view('layouts/header');
    $this->load->model('loginm'); //llamo al modelo loginm para traer  la funcion Traer datos y poder consultar los datos de usuario
    $nombres['nombre'] = $this->loginm->TraerDatos($_SESSION['usuarios']);  //    comprobamos que el usuario exista en la base de datos y la password ingresada sea correcta
    $this->load->view('layouts/menu', $nombres);
    $this->load->model('agenda/agendaM');
   $this->load->view('layouts/footer');
```

}

en la función del controlador envió el mismo dato al modelo donde hago la consulta en la base da tos y retorno el id que vuelve a otra vista donde entrego el detalle

MODELO:

```
function traeCausa($id = NULL)
{
    $this->db->where("id", $id);
    $this->db->limit(1);
    return $this->db->get('causas_informe')->result_array();
}
```

Al momento de entregar los datos del controlador a la nueva vista me da null, mi duda es como puedo solucionar esto o como revisar que dato viaja y donde es que se cae la consulta. 
Saludos

Answer (score 0):

deberías llamar una sola vista desde tu controlador, la vista del template donde vas a hacer todo tu proceso, y puedes enviarle como parámetro la ruta de la vista que vas a cargar el formulario y en el template cargas el header, el contenido (la vista que recibes como parametro) y el footer.

```
public function actualizaAgenda($id = NULL){
   $this->load->model('loginm'); 
   $data['nombre'] = $this->loginm->TraerDatos($_SESSION['usuarios']);
   $data['vista'] = 'layouts/menu';//La vista especifica que deseas cargar
   $this->load->view('layouts/template_principal', $data);
}
```

Espero que sea lo que buscas. Esto te servirá hasta codeigniter 3.